# Windows AD not updating Linux DDNS in hybrid integration

Tags: active-directory, bind, windows-server-2019, isc-dhcp, ddns

I am setting up a Windows AD server, with a Linux DDNS setup. The Linux DDNS runs perfectly fine as expected. However, when I try to add the AD role to the Windows Enterprise 2019 server, the role installs as expected but it does not update the primary DNS database with SRV records for the zone.

In wireshark, during and after the Windows AD setup I can see queries to the primary DNS for the SRV records, to which the primary DNS responds with "no such name".

I have allowed update/query for the AD server in named.conf.local on the primary DNS, and the AD server is set to use the address of the primary DNS server as its DNS server.

I have tried a fresh install of the AD server twice now and got the same issue each time. I have no idea what could be the issue - could a potential solution just be to add all of the necessary SRV records to the database file manually?

I have added the configs below (I know the allow addresses grant too many permissions in `named.conf.local` but I was just experimenting and trying to get this to work as it is my first time setting it up).

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "lims.co.uk" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.lims.co.uk";
        notify yes;
        allow-update {
                192.168.80.3;
                192.168.80.7;
                192.168.80.8;
                192.168.80.9;
                localnets;
        };
        allow-query {
                127.0.0.1;
                192.168.80.3;
                192.168.80.5;
                192.168.80.6;
                192.168.80.7;
                192.168.80.8;
                192.168.80.9;
                localnets;
        };
        allow-transfer {
                192.168.80.3;
                192.168.80.5;
                192.168.80.6;
                192.168.80.7;
                192.168.80.8;
                192.168.80.9;
        };
};

zone "80.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.80.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        notify yes;
        allow-update {
                192.168.80.3;
                192.168.80.7;
                192.168.80.8;
                192.168.80.9;
                localnets;
        };
        allow-query {
                127.0.0.1;
                192.168.80.3;
                192.168.80.5;
                192.168.80.6;
                192.168.80.7;
                192.168.80.8;
                192.168.80.9;
                localnets;
        };
        allow-transfer {
                192.168.80.3;
                192.168.80.5;
                192.168.80.6;
                192.168.80.7;
                192.168.80.8;
                192.168.80.9;
        };
};
```

`/var/lib/bind/db.lims.co.uk`

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
lims.co.uk              IN SOA  lims.co.uk. admin\@lims.co.uk. (
                                2021032201 ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.lims.co.uk.
                        NS      ns2.lims.co.uk.
                        A       192.168.80.7
                        A       192.168.80.8
                        A       192.168.80.9
$ORIGIN lims.co.uk.
AD1                     A       192.168.80.7
BDC1                    A       192.168.80.8
BDC2                    A       192.168.80.9
ns1                     A       192.168.80.5
ns2                     A       192.168.80.6
dhcp                    A       192.168.80.3
```

`db.80.168.192.in-addr.arpa`

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
80.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN SOA  80.168.192.in-addr.arpa. admin\@lims.co.uk. (
                                2021032201 ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.lims.co.uk.
                        NS      ns2.lims.co.uk.
$ORIGIN 80.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
3                       PTR     dhcp.lims.co.uk.
5                       PTR     ns1.lims.co.uk.
6                       PTR     ns2.lims.co.uk.
7                       PTR     AD1.lims.co.uk.
8                       PTR     BDC1.lims.co.uk.
9                       PTR     BDC2.lims.co.uk.
$TTL 300        ; 5 minutes
99                      PTR     DESKTOP-9MFAP8Q.lims.co.uk.
```

> 192.168.80.3 DHCP
>
> 192.168.80.4 Primary DNS
>
> 192.168.80.5 Secondary DNS
>
> 192.168.80.6 Secondary DNS
>
> 192.168.80.7 Windows AD
>
> 192.168.80.8 Backup Domain Controller (not configured yet)
>
> 192.168.80.9 Backup Domain Controller (not configured yet)

Update:

I receive the following errors on my AD server.

> The DFS Replication service failed to contact domain controller  to access configuration information. Replication is stopped. The service will try again during the next configuration polling cycle, which will occur in 60 minutes. This event can be caused by TCP/IP connectivity, firewall, Active Directory Domain Services, or DNS issues.
>
> Additional Information:
> Error: 160 (One or more arguments are not correct.)

> This computer is now hosting the specified directory instance, but Active Directory Web Services could not service it. Active Directory Web Services will retry this operation periodically.
>
> Directory instance: NTDS
> Directory instance LDAP port: 389
> Directory instance SSL port: 636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to make AD work.

For some reason the Windows AD server was not dynamically uptading the DNS zone file. Potentially because Windows and Linux use different standards for SRV records - this may cause compatibility issues.

Therefore, I added the records manually by going to `%systemroot%\system32\config` and copying the contents of this file into the zone file. I also removed all of the `600`s from this file before copying into the zone file.

I incremented the serial number then ran

`sudo systemctl restart bind9`

`sudo systemctl status bind9`

This has fixed the issue and the backup domain controllers are now able to be set up.